# How can i check if the input does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if this input doesn't exist.

I have this condition for checking if the input exist but i want to do the opposite.

```
if ($('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]')) {
alert('Input exist.');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Guess it is wrong tagged, it has nothing to deal with PHP. It looks like JQuery question.

Answer (score 3):

If no length, input does not exist:

```
if (!$('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]').length) {
```

actually existance should be checked with length aswell, not the way you've done it:

```
if ($('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]').length) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time since the question was asked, but I found the check to be clearer like this :

```
if ($("#A").is('[myattr]')) {
    // attribute exists
} else {
    // attribute does not exist
}
```

(As found on this site [here](http://blog.routydevelopment.com/2010/07/how-to-check-if-an-attribute-exists-on-your-jquery-selection/))

**EDIT**

```
if ($('#A').attr('myattr')) {
    // attribute exists
} else {
    // attribute does not exist
}
```

The above will fall into the `else`-branch when `myattr` exists but is an empty string or "0". If that's a problem you should explicitly test on `undefined`:

```
if ($('#A').attr('myattr') !== undefined) {
    // attribute exists
} else {
    // attribute does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check visibility of that input with "visible" attribute

For example,

```
if ($('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]').is(':visible')) {
    alert('Input exist.');
}
```

Comment: you can check like this

$('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]:visible').attr('class')

This statement returns class of the visible element

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do a prev undefined check  :

```
var input = $('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]');

    if( typeof input === 'undefined') {
       alert('input not exist')
    }
```

then you can do :

```
    if (!$('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]').length || $('input[name="urlpdfvcmd"]') === "") {
        alert('Input not exist.');
    }
```